# Webpack unable to minify files

Tags: webpack

When I run webpack, the minified file it generates does not contain all the code. I will paste it below. First, the webpack config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var PROD = JSON.parse(process.env.PROD_ENV || '0');

module.exports = {
    // define entry point
    entry: {
        script1: './plugins/jquery.min.js',
        script2: './bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        script3: './plugins/modernizr.js',
        script4: './plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js',
        script5: './plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js',
        script6: './plugins/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js',
        script7: './plugins/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
        script8: './plugins/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js',
        script9: './plugins/jquery.countTo.min.js',
        script10: './plugins/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.min.js',
        script11: './plugins/jquery.validate.min.js',
        script12: './plugins/morphext/morphext.min.js',
        script13: './plugins/vide/jquery.vide.min.js',
        script14: './plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js',
        script15: './plugins/jquery.browser.min.js',
        script16: './plugins/SmoothScroll.min.js',
        script17: './public/js/template.min.js',
        script18: './plugins/jquery.knob.min.js'
    },
    // define output point
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: PROD ? 'bundle.min.js' : 'bundle.js'
    },
    externals: {
        'TweenLite': 'TweenLite'
    },
    plugins: PROD ? [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false }
        })
    ] : []

};
```

And the file is outputs is not what I was expecting. It is only a few lines of code. It is:

```
!function(t){function e(o){if(n[o])return n[o].exports;var r=n[o]={exports:{},id:o,loaded:!1};return t[o].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,e),r.loaded=!0,r.exports}var n={};return e.m=t,e.c=n,e.p="",e(0)}([function(t,e){!function(t){function e(t,e){return t.toFixed(e.decimals)}t.fn.countTo=function(e){return e=e||{},t(this).each(function(){function n(){s+=l,c++,o(s),"function"==typeof r.onUpdate&&r.onUpdate.call(i,s),c>=a&&(f.removeData("countTo"),clearInterval(d.interval),s=r.to,"function"==typeof r.onComplete&&r.onComplete.call(i,s))}function o(t){var e=r.formatter.call(i,t,r);f.text(e)}var r=t.extend({},t.fn.countTo.defaults,{from:t(this).data("from"),to:t(this).data("to"),speed:t(this).data("speed"),refreshInterval:t(this).data("refresh-interval"),decimals:t(this).data("decimals")},e),a=Math.ceil(r.speed/r.refreshInterval),l=(r.to-r.from)/a,i=this,f=t(this),c=0,s=r.from,d=f.data("countTo")||{};f.data("countTo",d),d.interval&&clearInterval(d.interval),d.interval=setInterval(n,r.refreshInterval),o(s)})},t.fn.countTo.defaults={from:0,to:0,speed:1e3,refreshInterval:100,decimals:0,formatter:e,onUpdate:null,onComplete:null}}(jQuery)}]);
```

How do I get it to minify all files listed and concat them into the single bundle.min.js?

Comment: There will be bundle created for every entry file.  I guess because of your naming convention they override each other. Do you want 18 different bundle files?  If not then you should put all the dependencies in one entry file. See https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output file is showing only a single library (countTo) being webpack'd. This is because you have multiple entry points and only a single output filename. So what's happening is that webpack is processing your entry points and constantly overwriting the bundle.js output file :)

In order to handle this setup, you should configure your output file name to something like:

```
output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: PROD ? '[name].bundle.min.js' : '[name].bundle.js'
},
```

See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename

However, if you follow this, you will end up with a minified file for each entry, definitely not what you want.

@Felix is onto something with the single entry file - take the files you have listed as entry points, put them into their own file, say `plugins.js`, where the contents look like this:

```
import './plugins/jquery.min.js';
import './bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import './plugins/modernizr.js';
...
```

Then, point your entry at it:

```
 entry: {
    plugins: './plugins.js',
 }
```

After running `webpack`, you should end up with `./dist/plugins.bundle.min.js` in PROD otherwise `./dist/plugins.bundle.js` .

You can read more about [how I've done it](https://brian.olore.net/wp/2017/06/journey-to-webpack-2/) here which also includes how to properly handle libraries like jQuery and modernizr.